# Slide down using css (hardware acceleration)

Tags: jquery, cordova, css-animations

I have an "stack" of children divs inside a wrapper container div. These children divs appear to slide down because new children are constantly appended to the top and given the .slideDown() animation, thus forcing all the other children down as well. This works fine but Im using it in a PhoneGap app and when done fast it appears choppy and jumpy. I heard this could be done better by making css transformations do it, which forces hardware acceleration (I think). However, every example I see seems to be trying much more complicated things than I need and I cant figure it out, so if this is possible any help would be appreciated.

jQuery code:

```
row.hide().prependTo('#blockArea').slideDown(1000, 'linear');
```

blockArea is the wrapper, row is the row being added.

Comment: Set the initial height to `0` and add `transition` to the CSS, create another class that has the right height, and add that class with javascript once the element is prepended, and ta-da !

Comment: I have the row height as 0 and I put the line " transition: height 1s ease-in" in the row class with it. Then I have another class with "height: 20%" that I add once prepended, but it doesnt do the transition, not sure of the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

It won't be so easy ...

If you really want to get better results using hardware acceleration, you can't rely on height transitions.

What should you do ? There are several posibilities, but I would recommend:

add the div as it is, without transitions. At the same time, set a transform on the wrapper in the style of

```
transform: translateY(***px);
```

this transform should be calculated to compensate the new div,  so that anything moves (the new div will be rendered above the current ones, and probable out of the viewport).

```
also, set a transition on transform of the time that you want.
```

Now, in a delayed function, change the transform to translateY(0px). It will be ok to do it in a setTimeout () of 0 milliseconds. You need to do it that way so that the transition is applied

Good luck !

Comment: Ok Im trying that but I dont think Im following completely. Im using row.prependTo('#blockArea'); which adds the row normally. Then I should add a class to the wrapper that contains transform: translateY(***px);...wouldnt that just move the whole blockArea down the page not the rows?

Comment: Not exactly. My suggestion is to use translateY to move it up the page. The net result would be that the movement downwards of the div inserted wouldn't show. and moving the blockArea should move the rows, because the rows are inside rowarea